# Prove that $\mathbb{Z} / \mathrm{Ker}$ $f$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{f}(\mathbb{Z} )$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, graph-isomorphism

Let $f\colon (\mathbb{Z},+) \rightarrow(\mathbb{Q}-\{0\}, \cdot)$ be defined by
$$f(m)=\left\{\begin{array}{c}1, \text { if } m \text { is even } \\ -1, \text { if } m \text { is odd }\end{array}\right.$$
Show that  $f$ is a homomorphism.   Determine $\ker f$ and also  prove that $\mathbb{Z} / \ker f$ is isomorphic to $f(\mathbb{Z})$
( $\mathbb{Z} $ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are the set of integers and rational numbers respectively).

***My approach:***

Let $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$.
Suppose  both $m$ and $n$ are even. Then $m+n$ is even and so
$$f(m+n)=1=1\cdot 1=f(m)f(n)$$

If  both $m$ and $n$ are odd. Then $m+n$ is even and so
$$f(m+n)=1=(-1)\cdot (-1)=f(m)f(n)$$
If one of $m$ and $n$ is even and other is odd then $m+n$ is odd. In this case $f(m+n)=-1=f(m)f(n)$.
Hence $f$ is a homomorphism.

*2nd part*

$\ker(f)=\{x\in \mathbb{Z}\mid f(x)=1\}=\{x\in \mathbb{Z}\mid x \mbox{ is even}\}.$.
I stuck here to show $\mathbb{Z} / \ker$ $f$ is isomorphic to $f(\mathbb{Z} )$.  How can I show this?

Comment: What are the cosets of $\ker(f)$? Can you find a simple function from the set of cosets to the group $f(\mathbb{Z})$? Show that this function is an isomorphism.

Comment: This whole problem is just a mere application of Firtst Isomorphism Theorem(https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FirstGroupIsomorphismTheorem.html). Start from thinking about the condition in which $f(m)=f(n)$. $f(m)=f(n)$ iff $f(m-n)=1$ iff $m-n$ is in kernel of $f$ iff $n\in m+\mbox{ker}(f)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** If $\varphi : G \rightarrow G'$ is a group homomorphism, then there exists an injective map
$$\overline{\varphi} : G/\mathrm{Ker}(\varphi) \rightarrow G'$$

such that $\mathrm{Im}(\overline{\varphi})= \mathrm{Im}(\varphi)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your 1st part is OK.

For the 2nd part, note that $\operatorname{ker}f=\{m\in\Bbb Z\mid f(m)=1 \}=\{m\in\Bbb Z\mid m\text{ is even}\}=2\Bbb Z$; hence, $\Bbb Z/\operatorname{ker} f=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z=\{0,1\}^+$; show that the map $\{0,1\}^+\to \{1,-1\}^\times=f(\Bbb Z)$, defined by $0\mapsto 1, \space1\mapsto-1$ (there's no other candidate for an isomorphism) is indeed a bijective(!) homomorphism, namely an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to check $E=\mbox{ker}(f)$ and $O=\mathbb{Z}-E$ partitions $\mathbb{Z}$, each of them corresponds to the image $1, -1$. Then construct the set $\overline{Z}=\mathbb{Z}/E=\{E, O\}$ and define an operation $+$ on $\overline{Z}$ such that $E+E=E, E+O=O+E=O, O+O=O$. Then check that $(\overline{Z},+)$ is a group. Now think about a function $\phi:\overline{Z}\to \mbox{im}(f)$ such that $\phi(E)=1, \phi(O)=-1$. Can you proceed from here?

The point is (1) to define an operation $+$ to make $\overline{Z}=\mathbb{Z}/\mbox{ker}(f)$ into a group (2) to check there is a group isomorphism(a bijective homomorphism between groups) from $\overline{Z}$ to $\{-1, 1\}$.